# Confluent RabbitMqSourceConnector query

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using confluent platform, schema registry and rabbitmq source connector.

For flow 1, I have a Kafka producer that sends messages to a kafka topic - payments, based on a pojo, Payment, and uses value.serializer - io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer and validates the message using the Schema registry. The Schema Registry has a schema for Payment. The consumer uses a value.deserializer - io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer to consume the payment.

For flow 2, it uses RabbitMqSourceConnector that takes messages from rabbitmq queue and sends them to same kafka topic (as above) - payments. The Json message has the same fields as flow 1 payment with additional optional fields. The additional optional fields can be ignored during deserialisation.

For both flows, I would like to use the same consumer with KafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.

For flow2, I have tried different value.converters:

1. org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter. I can see the message as a json string or text.  But the consumer deserializer io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer does not work, I have to change it to org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
2. org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter. It encodes the message.
   The io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer does not work. Unknown magic byte!
3. io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter.  During setting the value.converter, it complains with existing schema:  Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema for subject

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Last I checked, the RabbitMQ connector documentation explicitly say only bytes or strings are supported, so it's not possible to use the same deserializer

Comment: Is there a way to transform the input message to pojo kafka schema serialised message?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You can use `HoistField` transform in Connect, for example, to create a struct from the string/bytes record, but then you would need a pojo with just one field for that singular key/value. If you want more detailed conversions than that, best to use KSQL/Kafka Streams to map to new structured objects